# Summation of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

I am having difficulty performing the following summation. I think there might be simple sum, but i am unable to see how to get there. Any help would be much appreciated.

$$\sum_{m=1}^{N-1} \frac{sin\left(\frac{\pi m}{N}\right)sin\left(\frac{\pi n m}{N}\right)}{sin^2\left(\frac{\pi m}{2N}\right)}$$

Note that n and N are positive integers.

Many thanks
Lee

Comment: See that $\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi m}N)}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi m}{2N})}=2\cot(\frac{\pi m}{2N})$, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also found this substitution, but I could not see how to proceed.

Comment: By inspection, I have found the sum to be =2 (N-n). However, i still cannot do the math to get there!

Comment: That surely should not be the case.  Consider $n=0$ or $N=0$.

Comment: Thanks Simple Art, there is no case n=0 or N=0, only positive integers.